# "Find the recurrence formula that defines this sequence": Which of these answers is better?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$U_n=n\cdot(-1)^n$

The answer I got was $U_{k+1}=-U_k+(-1)^{k+1}$, but the textbook's answer is $U_{k+1}=U_k-(-1)^k(2k+1)$. Is one answer preferred over the other for any reason, or does it not matter?

Comment: Hi -- welcome to math.SE! [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Both are correct. I cannot see any reason to prefer one over the other.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer your answer; it captures more of the gist of the relationship between $U_k$ and $U_{k+1}$, and it uses $k$ (outside of indices) once instead of twice. The textbook's answer is actually more complicated than the explicit expression for $U_n$.

Anyway, a textbook that asks you to find "the" recurrence formula that defines this sequence can't be a very good textbook; it should be obvious that a sequence can be defined through different recurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers are correct. A reason that the textbook might prefer the second form is that you can proceed directly to finding a closed form for the recurrence by summing the second term.